# Is there a shorter way to declare multidimensional vectors?

Tags: c++, vector

The way that I declare multidimensional vectors in C++ of a given size is very verbose:

```cpp
int a = 3, b = 4, c = 5;
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> vec(a, std::vector<std::vector<int>>(b, std::vector<int>(c, 0)));
```

Is there any way to make this shorter?

Comment: `using std::vector; vector<vector<vector<int>>> vec{ 3, {4, vector<int>(5, 0)}};`

Comment: `template <typename T>
using vector3d = std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<T> > >;`. 
Use: `vector3d<int> x;`

Comment: `std::vector<int> vec(a * b * c);` and then use index arithmetic. Nesting `std::vector`s introduces indirection overhead.

Comment: continuing @Evg's thought, I would probably write a Vector3d class that handles the index arithmetic, or even a template that can accept varying dimension counts